# serie $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left (\frac{1-k}{1+k}\right )^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Can somebody please help me with this serie?
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left (\frac{1-k}{1+k}\right )^k $$
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1-k}{1+k}=-1 $$
But i think that my solution is wrong (i did root test first) how should i evaluate this?

any suggestion would be great

Thanks

Comment: what is your solution? I guess you are using the root test?

Comment: "my solution is wrong", to what question?

Comment: yes i used root test and then did the limit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write it as $(-1)^k (\frac{k-1}{k+1})^k = (-1)^k (1 - \frac2{k+1})^k$, and now it's easy to see that

- $(1 - \frac{2}{k+1})^k \to e^{-2}$ as $k \to \infty$;
- $(-1)^k (1 - \frac2{k+1})^k$ does not have a limit as $k \to \infty$: it alternates between numbers close to $e^{-2}$ and numbers close to $-e^{-2}$.

Therefore the sum cannot converge.